# ajax request through link_to with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to do an AJAX request, form a link_to helper, that also contains params.

```
<%= link_to 'Bookmark', bookmarks_path(user_id: @user.id, week_number: @week_number, year: @answers.last.created_at.year), remote: true %>
```

the error I get in my console is:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: bookmark:
```

the other issue is that it fires off a POST and GET request, both return in a 404.
My bookmarks controller:

```
  def create
    @bookmark = current_user.bookmarks.create(bookmark_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js
    end
  end

  private

  def bookmark_params
    params.require(:bookmark).permit(:user_id, :week_number, :year)
  end
```

is this the incorrect way to go about doing this, and how do I fix the issues I'm having?

Answer (score 0):

For creating bookmark through ajax, you need to make form like:-

```
<%= form_for @bookmark, remote: true do |f|%>
    <%= f.select :weak_number, collection_of_values %>
    <%= f.select :year, collection_of_values %>
<% end %>
```

Also, there is no need to permit user_id.So, remove from bookmark_params method. current_user.bookmarks will set user_id in bookmark record.

Comment: user_id is actually required, I have a foreign key for the actual user creating it!

Comment: yeah, current_user.bookmarks will set the foreign key for the user who is creating this boorkmark.